# Cross platform string encryption

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, encryption

I am looking for a method of encrypting a string on an iPhone, passing that to a web server (asp.net c#) and decrypting it there for processing, and return a response.

I think that I know how to send the encrypted string and then return the result, but I don't know what encryption will work on iPhone and asp.net.

Any suggestions? Sample code would be helpful, especially on the iPhone side, if at all possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

read this:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html

[What's the best encryption algorithm for the iPhone in terms of speed and security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999354/whats-the-best-encryption-algorithm-for-the-iphone-in-terms-of-speed-and-securit)

[AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)